# Listbox: Get Index for double click

Tags: python, tkinter

This seems like a real simple problem, but i fail to find a working solution. I need to get the index of the selected item in my Listbox after a double click. But this seems to be harder than it looks. I tried *listbox.get(ACTIVE)* which is working, but only gives me the text, not the index. Next I tried *listbox.curselection()* which is not working and only returns an empty tuple. I found one answer that suggested to use "Button-Released" because the Button-Pressed event fires before the selection is changed. But I don't know of any "double click released". So how do I get the index of the element that was double-clicked?

```
def doubleClick(event):
    print(box.curselection()) #not working, returns empty touple
    print(box.get(ACTIVE)) #working, but returns the text of the clicked item, not the index
    

box = Listbox(master_frame)
box.grid(row=0, column=0)
box.bind("<Double-Button-1>", doubleClick)
```

Comment: `box.curselection()` works and gives the correct index in my Windows 10 with Python 3.10.3.

Comment: Thanks for checking it - it doesn't work on my Linux-System with Python 3.8.10

Comment: It also works in my RHEL with Python 3.9.7 and 2.6.6.